# Python code not iterating through more than one item in list

Tags: python, loops

I am making a self painting program. paint_at() paints the selected color at x and y coordinates (stating at 0, ending at 31). select_color() selects the color in hex format. The issue comes in with the `for code in hex_codes:` loop. what I think is happening is that it doesn't iterate more than one pixel if it isn't an instant match. I don't want this. Instead, I want it to cycle through all the codes in the painting, and paint only the matches. Below is the output of each iteration of the loop. As you can see, #000000 checks everything, while the rest give up after one pixel. Is anyone able to figure out what's going on?

```
Color: #000000, Code: #75403a
Color: #000000, Code: #b57051
Color: #000000, Code: #753e39
Color: #000000, Code: #b86f4f
Color: #000000, Code: #754038
Color: #000000, Code: #e3a870
Color: #000000, Code: #6a4437
Color: #000000, Code: #347243
Color: #000000, Code: #7a9a5b
Color: #000000, Code: #347241
Color: #000000, Code: #67c451
Color: #000000, Code: #7c9c5b
Color: #000100, Code: #000000
Color: #020200, Code: #000000
Color: #010300, Code: #000000
Color: #020401, Code: #000000
Color: #000501, Code: #000000
Color: #040402, Code: #000000
```

My code:

```
x_count = 0
y_count = 0
num = 1
painted = []
while num < len(hex_codes):
    color = hex_codes[num-1]
    if color not in painted:
        if color == "#ffffff":
            color = hex_codes[num]
        select_color(color)
        time.sleep(0.02)
        for code in hex_codes:
            print("Color: " + color + ", Code: " + code)
            if code == color:
                paint_at(x_count, y_count)
            x_count += 1
            if x_count == 32:
                x_count = 0
                y_count += 1
            if y_count == 32:
                break
        painted.append(color)
    num +=1
```

Comment: Please provide full code (Ex: hex_codes initialization is missing)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think when the inner loop finishes, the `x_count` and `y_count` variables are not being reset to their initial values, which causes the program to continue painting from the last pixel of the previous color instead of starting from the top left corner.

To fix this, you can reset `x_count` and `y_count` to 0 after the inner loop finishes. This ensures that the program starts painting from the top left corner for each color.

```
painted = []
for code in hex_codes:
    if code not in painted:
        select_color(code)
        time.sleep(0.02)
        for i in range(32 * 32):
            if hex_codes[i] == code:
                paint_at(x_count, y_count)
            x_count += 1
            if x_count == 32:
                x_count = 0
                y_count += 1
            if y_count == 32:
                break
        painted.append(code)
        x_count = 0
        y_count = 0
```

Answer (score 0):

One problem that sticks out is the fact that when you are iterating through the loop, you are incrementing the x_count and y_count variables without returning them to their initial values for each new color. The loop will continue to search successive pixels using the erroneous coordinates if a match is not found on the initial pixel, in other words.

Maybe you should try this, you should reset x_count and y_count to 0 at the beginning of each iteration of the loop:

```
    for code in hex_codes:
        x_count = 0
        y_count = 0
        print("Color: " + color + ", Code: " + code)
        if code == color:
            paint_at(x_count, y_count)
        x_count += 1
        if x_count == 32:
            x_count = 0
            y_count += 1
        if y_count == 32:
            break
```

I hope this helps thanks!